# What is the best practise of using same Model on several projects?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I create a ReactJS app using Sequelize and PostgreSQL database. I defined my models on my ReactJS API, but I need to use the same database (so the same models) on an other API.

How should I do so without writing again the definition of each model, because if I made a change, I would have to do it everywhere. Is there a better way to handle this king of problem?

**Why I don't use the ReactJS API?** Because when I built my React app, the API disappears: I'm using proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the models in their own separate Node.js package, so they could be reused by both.

Please, refer to this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules

Comment: How should I do that? What do you call « their on separate Node.js package »?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myModel = require('./models/myModel');
```

you can add by require here my model is in root directory inside model folder.